# 3 column layout will not fill width of screen

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to html/css and I'm having a problem with a project. I am trying to create a 3 column layout for the bottom portion of my page. What I have right now is close to what I want, but it does not fill the width of the screen. It's all bunched on the left side and does not stretch to match the screen. I went back and followed the example from w3schools and it still didn't work. What am I missing?

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <h1>FOLLOW ME ON <br> INSTAGRAM</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>contact me</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h1>SUBSCRIBE</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.column {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.column.side { 
    width: 25%;
}

.column.middle { 
    width: 50%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: ".column.side" ".column.middle" you do not have classes like that in HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1.) As @chojnicki wrote in a comment, you need to add the classes defined in the CSS (`.side`, `.middle`) to your HTML

2.) To include the `padding` in the `width` in order to get a sum of exactly 100% overall (and *not* more than that to avoid the last column to go under the second one) for the added widths (25% + 50% + 25%), you need to add `box-sizing: border-box;` to everything (using the `*`selector):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.column.side {
  width: 25%;
}

.column.middle {
  width: 50%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column side">
    <h1>FOLLOW ME ON <br> INSTAGRAM</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="column middle">
    <h2>contact me</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="column side">
    <h1>SUBSCRIBE</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna have padding "inside" element, then you need to set `box-sizing: border-box`.

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column.side { 
  width: 25%;
}

.column.middle { 
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column side">
    <h1>FOLLOW ME ON <br> INSTAGRAM</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="column middle">
    <h2>contact me</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="column side">
    <h1>SUBSCRIBE</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use .col-xs-4?
and you shouldn't use width to your cols so why do you use col?